# Can I trigger a js function without mouse or keyboard

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I use a `<a>href` call. I understood that the above wasn't a good practice (calling a JavaScript function in href), but a lot of web pages use href call js function, so I need to know how to trigger the js `myfunction` without performing mouse or keyboard. How can I do that?

```
<a href="javascript:myfunction('abc');" class="button">
```

Comment: What event are you trying to associate a function with? It has to be associated with something. Also, it doesn't matter if the entire world is using inline JavaScript, that doesn't make it okay for you to do. Don't expect others to help you when you're deliberately performing bad practices from over a decade, decade-and-a-half ago.

Answer (score 1):

How about using onLoad event inside body tag ?